# Active Directory Admin Denied Access - Why?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

Logged in as the domain admin of an Active Directory environment, I'm attempting to run this command to reboot a workstation:

```
@start /b cmd /c shutdown -r -f -t 1 -m \\COMPUTER-NAME
```

I'm getting this error:

```
COMPUTER-NAME: Access is denied
```

Why would the domain admin be denied access to execute this command?

Comment: IMO, this shouldn't happen! Can you check if the workstation is having group policy applied (check if domain admins is in the Administrators group), and the proper SMB settings. I once encountered this problem when SMB2 was disabled on a Windows 7 desktop, and had to manually enable through regedit!

Comment: Is the problem specific to the shutdown command, or does it also fail if you try `dir \\COMPUTER-NAME\c$` ?

Comment: Another setting to check is "Access this computer from the network" under User Rights Assignment in the local security policy.  Also the corresponding "Deny access to this computer from the network".

Comment: @HarryJohnston : "dir \\COMPUTER-NAME\c$" produces error "The target account name is incorrect". I'm not sure what is meant by target account, but I've verified that "computer-name" is correct.

Comment: The workstation might not be properly joined to the domain.  I recommend logging into the workstation interactively using the local administrator account, double-checking that the computer is using the right computer name, and leaving and then re-joining the domain.

Comment: ... the target account name problem can also occur in some scenarios involving multiple domains, e.g., if `computer-name` is in domain A but you're trying to connect to it from a machine in domain B and there is a computer object in domain B that is also named `computer-name`.

Comment: ... or if the computer you're logged into is getting the wrong IP address when it looks up `computer-name`, try `ping COMPUTER-NAME` and then log into the workstation and check that the IP address it is using is the same one.

Comment: @HarryJohnston : Pining "computer-name" showed the wrong IP address! Although I had correct dhcp reservations involving the proper mapping of this computer's MAC address and current IP, DNS contained a HOST(A) record from 2015 that pointed to the wrong IP Address. After removing that dns record, the reboot command succeeded. Thanks so much for you keen diagnostic suggestions.

Comment: @LonnieBest - I'd suggest you to better leave a helpful answer for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by a DNS Host(A) record that got auto-created 4 years ago: where another computer (renamed since) use to have the same name as the current computer I was trying to remotely reboot. That old record pointed to a different IP address than what the current computer (with that same name) is currently using via a dhcp reservation.

Harry Johnston suggested this command:

```
dir \\COMPUTER-NAME\c$
```

That produce this error:

```
The target account name is incorrect.
```

He also suggested pining "computer-name", which showed the wrong IP address!

So, I guess the shutdown command would not permit the reboot, because the computer that this old dns record pointed to was not the computer I was trying to reboot; the name in DNS did not match the name on the computer specified in the shutdown command. "Accessed denied", was all the shutdown command produced. Its too bad it wouldn't indicate WHY access was denied.

Anyway, after removing that old dns record, the remote reboot succeeded.